# Como fazer um select no formato de data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Como faço para realizar um select utilizando datas no `SQL server 2008`?
Quando eu faço uma busca com esse select:

```
select * from NOME_TABELA where DATA_FISCAL between '2016-05-01' and '2016-05-11'
```

O resultado são 12 registros inclusive um registro tem a informação da data como `"2016-05-11 00:00:00.000"`.

Quando faço o select:

```
" select * from NOME_TABELA where DATA_FISCAL like '2016-05-11 00:00:00.000' "
```

ou

```
" select * from NOME_TABELA where DATA_FISCAL = '2016-05-11 00:00:00.000' "
```

O SQL não encontra nenhum registro.

Outra dúvida que me intriga, é que quando vou dar um insert nesta tabela, aparece este erro.
"Falha ao converter data e/ou hora da cadeia de caracteres."

Alguém sabe o motivo deste erro? e como resolver ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] sua pergunta, e colocar a estrutura da tabela?

Answer (score 3):

Tenta assim: 
Primeiro faça um select para verificar se o formato é date ou datetime.
Em seguida use os seus parâmetros dessa maneira -

```
//Use o seu formato de data
SELECT * FROM NOME_TABELA 
WHERE DATA_FISCAL BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#;
```

[Fonte](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

Answer (score 1):

**Respondendo**, o erro no *insert* se dá porque você tenta informar a data num formato não esperado pelo banco, e o resultado inesperado no *select* se dá pelo mesmo motivo.

**Explicando**: o formato da data como string aceito pelo SQL Server, por padrão, depende da **linguagem** do usuário que se está usando para conectar ao banco, a qual é definida, por padrão, de acordo com a  linguagem de instalação do próprio SQL Server, a qual é definida, por padrão, de acordo com a linguagem do sistema operacional.

Mas a linguagem do usuário pode ser sobrescrita também por **configurações da sessão**, e o próprio formato de data aceita como string também pode ser sobrescrito por configurações da sessão.

Quando você acha que encontrou o formato correto e passa a utilizá-lo por todo o seu código, eventualmente este código vai rodar em um ambiente ligeiramente diferente e vai passar a dar erro, ou pior: vai passar a trazer resultados incorretos ou salvar no banco informações incorretas.

A boa prática é utilizar **parâmetros** para informar datas ou qualquer outro valor nos comandos SQL, isso evita este e outros problemas em potencial.

Se precisar informar a data como string, sem utilizar parâmetros, informe-a em um dos dois formatos **universalmente aceitos pelo SQL Server** independentemente de configurações. A saber:

- **yyymmdd** para data,
- ou **yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss[.mmm]** para data e hora.

Isso vai servir tanto para **insert** quanto para **select** ou qualquer outro comando.

<sub>Obs: estes dois formatos são padrão ISO.</sub>

No seu caso, o select informando data e hora ficaria assim:

```
select * from NOME_TABELA where DATA_FISCAL = '2016-05-11T00:00:00.000'
```